# How to use 一般 and examples

Tags: grammar, usage

一般 is both an adjective and adverb that means "same". I haven't found any thorough explanations of its usage. **How is it generally used and in what kind of situations?**

Thank you so much!

Comment: In case it's useful, there's a fair number of sites which give example sentences, e.g.: [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/), [YouDao](http://youdao.com/), and [ChinesePod](https://chinesepod.com/dictionary/english-chinese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一般

1. [like] e.g. (像)鬼**一般** =  **like** a ghost
2. [normal] e.g. **一般**人  = **normal** people
3. [average] e.g. **一般**水平 **average** level

To use 一般 as an adverb, you need to place a descriptive phrase before it, and then add an adverb marker 地 after it.

Example:

[瘋了一般地][攻擊] = [attack] [like being crazy]

*瘋了一般地 is an adverbal phrase*

[殺雞一般地][屠殺敵人] =  [Slaughter the enemies] [like Killing chickens]

*殺雞一般地 is an adverbal phrase*

Answer (score 1):

adj

他與計算機一般，算術都很快。He is just like a computer and he calculates so quickly.

他 He

與 and

計算機 computer

一般 same、like (equal)

算數 calculate

都 both

很 so、very

快 fast quick

adv (X I am not sure. I have not heard)

Answer (score 1):

Use 一般來說，[situation], here [situation] is somethings that will occurred generally speaking. For example, 一般來說，這個時間天氣都很熱。(Generally speaking, it is hot at this time)(一般來說，[situation], here [situation] is 這個時間天氣都很熱). So 這個時間天氣都很熱(It is hot at this time) is the things that happened generally speaking.

一般 can mean normal. 這東西很重，不是一般人就可以搬動的。(This stuff is heavy which cannot be moved by normal people).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers.

When you use 一般 to describe “average”, even though it literally means "average", but in real situations, it is a polite way of saying "bad". For example, if A is invited to B's family dinner. When coming back A's roommate C asked how B's mom's cook is. A didn't like it but didn't want to say anything bad about it. So A said "一般般吧".   In another case A hate it so much but don't want to be rude, A can say "非常一般" which means "very very bad" but less aggressive.

Comment: Before， I learned in Youtube that 一般般 means "normal" and equal to 马马虎虎. So it does mean "bad".

Comment: 一般般 or 马马虎虎 may also be used as 自谦. In such case, it should not be translated into "bad".

Comment: @tsh 自谦is a special situation that one reject others praise. In that case you can use any word means, generally, "bad", even though some are used more often than others. It's not a nature of the word but a context. How to translate it into another culture is another topic.